# Is "secure a job" informal?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

Is "secure a job" informal? What formal verbs can I use other than "obtain"?

Answer (score 2):

"Secure", with reference to obtaining a job, is certainly used within the workplace, so it is as formal as any other kind of workplace terminology. You might consider other words in place of 'job', such as *role*, *post*, or *position*. I would confidently write to a prospective employer "*..should I be successful in securing this role...*"

If you were speaking in the past tense about a job you did secure, another formal expression is "I *took* the post..." or "I *took up* the position..."

Comment: What are some informal ways to express this? "Land" a job? I often cannot distinguish them and I'd like to avoid informal terms in my essay.